# Janela do navegador do tamanho da tela sem scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber como é possível fazer uma página que não tenha scroll e que se adapte ao tamanho exato da tela.

como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: `body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}`

Comment: isso mesmo tendo mais conteudo nao fará com que haja scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tirar o scroll esconda o que está fora com `overflow: hidden` em CSS, como abaixo:

```
html,
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%
    height: 100%;
}
```

---

E se você se refere ao tamanho da resolução da tela então basta pedir a tela cheia para um elemento ao navegador através da função utilizada no código abaixo (*Elemento* > *Pedir tela cheia*). Funciona com todo elemento, exceto os nativos como "body", etc. Funciona só com eventos de clique e outros.

Exemplo:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("full_screen");

btn.onclick = function() {

        // Seu container para tela cheia
        var page = document.getElementById('page');

        /*
         * É necessário de condições para saber se tem suporte para tela cheia.
         * Não use os operadores ||.
         */
        if(page.requestFullscreen) {
            page.requestFullscreen();
        }else if(page.msRequestFullscreen) {
            /* IE, Edge */
            page.msRequestFullscreen();
        }else if(page.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            /* Firefox */
            page.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }else if(page.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            /* Chrome, Opera, Safari, etc */
            page.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }else{
            alert("Sem suporte para tela cheia.");
        }

}
```